# Bound on the sequence satisfying $z_{n+1} \leq cz_n^{1+\epsilon}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $z_n$ be a sequence of numbers such that
$$z_{n+1} \leq cz_n^{1+\epsilon}$$
for a constant $c>0$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

If $z_0$ is sufficiently small, is it possible to say that
$$z_n \leq f(n)$$
where $f(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$? $f$ may depend on $\epsilon$ and $z_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating the inequality we get
$$\begin{align*}
z_{n+1}&\le c\,z_n^{1+\epsilon}\\
&\le c^{1+(1+\epsilon)}\,z_{n-1}^{(1+\epsilon)^2}\\
&\le c^{1+(1+\epsilon)+(1+\epsilon)^2}\,z_{n-2}^{(1+\epsilon)^3}\\
&\le\dots\\
&\le c^{1+(1+\epsilon)+(1+\epsilon)^2+\dots+(1+\epsilon)^n}\,z_0^{(1+\epsilon)^{n+1}}\\
&=c^{\tfrac{(1+\epsilon)^n-1}{\epsilon}}\,z_0^{(1+\epsilon)^{n+1}}\\
&=c^{-1/\epsilon}\,z_0^{1+\epsilon}\bigl(c^{1/\epsilon}\,z_0\bigr)^{(1+\epsilon)^n}.
\end{align*}$$
If $c^{1/\epsilon}\,z_0<1$, then $z_n\to0$.